# Перехват http-трафика

Tags: c#, http, пакет, сниффер

Подскажите пожалуйста, как перехватывать http-запросы в c#? **Мне нужно просто знать, на какие сайты переходили и всё.**

---

Пробовал с помощью SharpPcap перехватывать пакеты, но я не знаю, что с ними делать дальше. Вот код:

```
// Когда приходит пакет, вызывается это событие
private static void Program_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
{
    Packet packet = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
    TcpPacket tcp = (TcpPacket)packet.Extract(typeof(TcpPacket));

    if (tcp != null)
    {
        byte[] data = tcp.PayloadData;
        string res = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

Но этот код печатает GET заголовки, и то только тогда, когда сайт не https. Надеюсь я понятно всё спросил. Спасибо.

Comment: на сколько я знаю, для работы с HTTPS трафиком вам придётся установить свой сертификат на машину, на которой снифается трафик. Тот же Fiddler просит установить их сертификат для расшифровки https трафика

Comment: @MrModest мне кажется, что я не в том направлении двигаюсь. Например, когда в браузере открываю http://mycsharp.ru/ (он без https), печатаются HTML-код этой страницы и и некоторые header'ы. А мне нужно, чтобы просто напечаталось http://mycsharp.ru/

Comment: попробуйте поискать ответ в этой статье: https://habr.com/sandbox/30450/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для HTTP-пакетов - парсить GET-запрос и искать параметр Host. Но его может и не быть, тогда сайт можно получить запросом к обратному DNS (если он там есть). Для HTTPS получить запросы без расшифровки трафика, понятное дело, нельзя, но можно попробовать найти SSL Handshake и посмотреть, к какому домену идет запрос.

Пример захвата HTTP и SSL/TLS трафика на первом найденном IPv4-интерфейсе, с использованием Raw Socket (для запуска требуются права администратора):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace ConsoleTest1
{    
    class Program
    {
        //Получает все локальные IP-адреса
        public static List<IPAddress> GetIpAddresses()
        {
            List<IPAddress> res = new List<IPAddress>(10);

            var ifs = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            foreach (var interf in ifs)
            {               

                var ipprop = interf.GetIPProperties();
                if (ipprop == null) continue;
                var unicast = ipprop.UnicastAddresses;
                if (unicast == null) continue;

                //находим первый Unicast-адрес
                foreach (var addr in unicast)
                {
                    if (addr.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork) continue;
                    res.Add(addr.Address);
                    break;
                }

            }

            return res;
        }

        const byte PROTO_TCP = 6;
        const byte SSL_HANDSHAKE = 0x16;

        public class ParseResult
        {
            public string TrafficType {get;set;}
            public string Host { get; set; }            
        }

        public static ParseResult ParseIpPacket(byte[] data, IPAddress src_ip)
        {
            ushort dummy;
            byte b;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms);
            uint header_len;
            uint total_len;
            IPAddress src,dst;
            string host="";
            ParseResult result;

            //parse IP packet header
            using (ms)
            using (br)
            {
                b = br.ReadByte();
                byte ver = (byte)((b & (byte)0xF0) >> 4); //IP version
                if (ver != 4)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unsupported IP version: {0}", ver);
                    return null;
                }                

                byte ihl = (byte)(b & (byte)0x0F);//header length
                header_len = ihl * 4u;

                b = br.ReadByte();

                //packet length
                byte[] temp = new byte[2];
                temp[1] = br.ReadByte();
                temp[0] = br.ReadByte();
                total_len = BitConverter.ToUInt16(temp, 0);

                dummy = br.ReadUInt16();
                dummy = br.ReadUInt16();

                byte ttl = br.ReadByte();
                byte proto = br.ReadByte();

                dummy = br.ReadUInt16();

                //source IP
                temp = new byte[4];
                temp[0] = br.ReadByte();
                temp[1] = br.ReadByte();
                temp[2] = br.ReadByte();
                temp[3] = br.ReadByte();
                src = new IPAddress(temp);                

                //destination IP
                temp[0] = br.ReadByte();
                temp[1] = br.ReadByte();
                temp[2] = br.ReadByte();
                temp[3] = br.ReadByte();
                dst = new IPAddress(temp);                

                if (proto != PROTO_TCP) return null;  
            }

            //Parse TCP packet
            uint tcp_size = total_len - header_len;
            byte[] tcp_data = new byte[tcp_size];
            Array.Copy(data, header_len, tcp_data, 0, tcp_size);

            ms = new MemoryStream(tcp_data);
            br = new BinaryReader(ms);
            byte tcp_header_size;
            uint http_size;

            using (ms)
            using (br)
            {
                var src_port = br.ReadUInt16();
                var dst_port = br.ReadUInt16();                
                br.ReadUInt32();
                br.ReadUInt32();
                tcp_header_size = (byte)(br.ReadByte() >> 4);
                tcp_header_size *= 4;
                http_size = tcp_size - tcp_header_size;
            }

            byte[] http_data = new byte[http_size];
            Array.Copy(tcp_data, tcp_header_size, http_data, 0, http_size);

            //parse SSL record
            if (http_data.Length >= 5 && src.Equals(src_ip))
            {
                ms = new MemoryStream(http_data);
                br = new BinaryReader(ms);
                using (ms)
                using (br)
                {                    
                    byte record_type = br.ReadByte();
                    byte b1 = br.ReadByte();
                    byte b2 = br.ReadByte();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[]{b2,b1};
                    ushort ssl_ver = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes,0);                    
                    ushort ssl_len = br.ReadUInt16();

                    if ( ((ssl_ver >= 0x0300 && ssl_ver <= 0x0304) || ssl_ver == 0x0002)
                        && (record_type == SSL_HANDSHAKE))
                    {                        
                        //пытаемся получить имя узла из обратного DNS
                        try
                        {
                            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(dst).HostName;
                        }
                        catch (SocketException)
                        {
                            host = "";
                        }

                        result = new ParseResult();
                        result.TrafficType = "SSL / TLS";
                        if (host != "") result.Host = host;                        
                        else result.Host = dst.ToString();                        
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Parse HTTP data
            string res = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(http_data);
            string[] arr = res.Split("\n\r".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (arr.Length > 2 && arr[0].StartsWith("GET") && arr[0].Contains("HTTP/"))
            {                
                //найдем поле Host
                for(int i=1;i<arr.Length;i++)
                {
                    if (arr[i].StartsWith("Host: "))
                    {
                        host = arr[i].Replace("Host: ", "");                        
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (host == "")
                {
                    //пытаемся получить имя узла из обратного DNS
                    try
                    {
                        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(dst).HostName;
                    }
                    catch (SocketException)
                    {
                        host = "";
                    }
                }

                result = new ParseResult();
                result.TrafficType = "HTTP";
                result.Host = host;                
                return result;
            }
            return null;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw,
                       ProtocolType.IP);

            var ips = GetIpAddresses();
            IPAddress ipaddr=new IPAddress(0L);
            foreach (var ip in ips)
            {
                if (ip.GetAddressBytes()[0] != 127)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Interface IP: {0}",ip);
                    ipaddr = ip;
                    break;
                }
            }

            mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipaddr, 0));


            mainSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,  //Applies only to IP packets
                           SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, //Set the include header
                           true);                           //option to true

            byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
            byte[] byOut = new byte[4];

            //Socket.IOControl is analogous to the WSAIoctl method of Winsock 2
            mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll,  //SIO_RCVALL of Winsock
                     byTrue, byOut);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*20];
            int res;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    res = mainSocket.Receive(buffer);                    

                    ParseResult result = ParseIpPacket(buffer, ipaddr);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}",result.TrafficType,result.Host);
                    }                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }           

        }
    }
}
```

Источники:

[CodeProject - A Network Sniffer in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C)

[Википедия - Протокол IPv4](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)

[Википедия - Протокол TCP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

[Cisco - SSL Introduction with Sample Transaction and Packet Exchange](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/secure-socket-layer-ssl/116181-technote-product-00.html#anc2)